# Regex in if condition of karate framework

Tags: regex, karate

Is it possible to use a regex in karate if condition as below

```
eval if ( xx!=“#regex [0-9]{7}”) karate.log(“success”)
```

I wanted to execute a if statement, regex evaluation is passed . Above code doesn’t evaluate as regex . It simply prints the log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `karate.match()`:

```
* def test = '123'
* if (karate.match(test, '#regex [0-9]+').pass) karate.log('pass')
```

Please refer to the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-match